# Hibernate group by criteria adds unwanted items to select list

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Is there a way to write Hibernate criteria so that it does not include the properties added using Projection.groupProperty in the select list?

I create my projection list like this:

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();

// I want these values included in the select list
projectionList
 .add(Projections.distinct("CAMPAIGN")) 
 .add(Projections.rowCount());

// I DO NOT want to select these values.  I only need the "group by"
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("CAMPAIGN"))
 .add(Projections.groupProperty("ad.ID"))
 .add(Projections.groupProperty("region.ID"));
```

Right now, the following query is generated:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT this_.CAMPAIGN AS y0_, 
                count(*)       AS y1_, 
                this_.CAMPAIGN AS y2_, 
                ad2_.ID        AS y3_, 
                region3_.ID    AS y4_ 
FROM   account this_ 
       INNER JOIN campaign campaign1_ 
               ON this_.CAMPAIGN = campaign1_.ID 
       INNER JOIN ad ad2_ 
               ON campaign1_.ID = ad2_.CAMPAIGN 
       INNER JOIN region region3_ 
               ON ad2_.ID = region3_.AD 
WHERE  this_.VENDOR = 4 
GROUP  BY this_.CAMPAIGN, 
          ad2_.ID, 
          region3_.ID
```

This returns many extra rows that would not be there if the last three items were not in the select list.

I want to create the same query WITHOUT

```sql
this_.CAMPAIGN as y2_, ad2_.ID as y3_, region3_.ID as y4_
```

as part of the select list.

That is, is there a way to `GROUP BY` items and not have them included in the select list?

Comment: Why do you add those unwanted properties to `projectionList`, if they are not intended to appear in the select list?

Comment: The first one ("CAMPAIGN") is included because Hibernate complains about it being required when using rowCount().  The other two are there to group the data so that there isn't one row for each combination of ad.ID x region.ID.  If I leave the last two out, I get N times the rows where N = num(ad.ID) x num(region.ID).